# How to make div whole width of page and move other elements down?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, css-position

I am currently working on the interface below:

[image]

When the user clicks on the formula a pane slides down to reveal a formula builder (not implemented yet) like so:

[image]

I would like to extend this pane from the far left to the far right side.  When I have attempted to use `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;` it will stretch, but  the elements below it won't slide down and get covered up.

**How can I get the element to span to the left and right and keep the below elements from getting covered?**

---

## HTML

```
<div class="editor-label">
       <label for="Calculator_Formula">Formula:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
    
    <span class="calculator-formula">
        <a href="#" class="solid-link" onclick=" $('.ui-formula-designer').slideDown('slow'); return false; ">(rrb * (currentValue + iv) - (hcv * homestead) - (mcv * military)) * levy</a>
    </span>
    
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Calculator.Formula" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    
    <div class="ui-formula-designer-container">
        <div class="ui-formula-designer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">
            <div class="designer" style="height: 150px;"></div>
            <div class="toolbox" style="height: 150px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### [Rough Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/6SqaQ/)

Comment: Can you provide us with some valid HTML (no MVC tags inside)? Or even better an online fiddle?

Comment: Don't use `position: absolute;` that way you take the element out of the layout and it, naturally, covers the rest of the page below it.

Comment: @RononDex I have added valid html and rough fiddler example

Comment: @Xareyo If I added `position: relative;` it would cause the element to stay bound within the parent which would stop it from spanning fully from the left to the right.

Comment: @Floremin If you have any other suggestions on how to solve this, please let me know.

Comment: The fiddle example works fine for me: panel expands and elements below slide down. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @Floremin I want the panel to span from the far left to the far right, almost as if the page is being split in half.

Comment: Move it out of the `#content` container then? `top-section{ padding 25px;}` `middle-section{ padding: 0px;}` `bottom-section{ padding: 25px; }`

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of a div **is** to stretch from far left to far right.

In your case, the surrounding container(s) might have some `margin` or `padding` applied.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new CSS class `.page-width` where I put elements that should not stretch from left to right, but have margin applied to them. Formula designer is not enclosed in a `<div>` with that class, so it stretches across the entire body width.

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6SqaQ/4/

You might need to make some fine adjustments, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment, firstly add this to your markup:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="top">
        content above the formula builder
    </div>
    <div class="ui-formula-designer-container">
    ....formula builder goes here.....
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        content below the formula builder
    </div>
</div>
```

Remove this padding from your CSS:

```
#content {
    padding: 25px;
}
```

Then add this (or the dimensions you need it to):

```
.top, .bottom {
    padding: 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6SqaQ/2/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [link](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/) as a reference. I was able to accomplish this with the following CSS:

```
.ui-formula-designer-container{
    position: relative;
}

.ui-formula-designer:before, .ui-formula-designer:after{
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #444;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.ui-formula-designer:before{
    left: 100%;
}

.ui-formula-designer:after{
    right: 100%;
}
```

## [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SqaQ/3/)